# k8s port-forward lost connection to pod

Tags: kubernetes, networking, cloud, microservices, system

I use port-forward to expose my service frontend as follows:

```bash
kubectl port-forward -n hotel-reserv svc/frontend 30096:5000
```

After that, I use a workload generator (i.e., wrk2) to send requests to `http://localhost:30096`, sometimes I met the following error messages:

```bash
E0323 16:12:26.434292 2362409 portforward.go:345] error creating error stream for port 30096 -> 5000: Timeout occurred
E0323 16:12:26.435372 2362409 portforward.go:368] error creating forwarding stream for port 30096 -> 5000: Timeout occurred
# Or error msgs like below
E0323 16:08:08.572355 2360819 portforward.go:407] an error occurred forwarding 30096 -> 5000: error forwarding port 5000 to pod d4cdf91e5f8726fc70f134ad3496ab185312b490c7c9022758a09e51b751b002, uid : container not running (d4cdf91e5f8726fc70f134ad3496ab185312b490c7c9022758a09e51b751b002)
```

The latter messages sometimes means that the port-forward will stop and I need to execute the command (i.e., `kubectl port-forward ...`) again.

Does there any solution to fix these errors?
How to keep `port-forward` work or restart after some errors occur? Or can I add some fields in `.yaml` of frontend service to keep its port-forward status?

Comment: I think your container in the pod behind the service is not available. Maybe it is being `OOM` as you ran a load test.

Comment: Since a `kubectl port-forward` targets a single Pod (even if it looks like you're targeting a Service) and gets routed through the Kubernetes API server, it's not really the right tool for a load test.  Can you run the load generator inside the cluster, or directly target a NodePort or LoadBalancer service?

Comment: I use NodePort in my frontend service. But how can the load generator directly target a NodePort? Should I set a external ip for the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `LoadBalancer` with `minikube tunnel` instead of `NodePort` and it works now.

Comment: `minikube service <service-name> --url` also works but has a dynamic port.